# osx spotlight open primary display

Tags: macos, display, display-settings, spotlight

Is there a way to make spotlight always open in the primary display? I went through the options for spotlight and display options and there doesn't seem to be a place for that in the normal settings.

Using Yosemite

Answer (score 1):

Spotlight is controlled by Dock. Spotlight will therefore be displayed on the display your Dock is set to. I suggest setting up your dock on the right/leftmost side of your main display.

Comment: dock is already on my main display but if the focus is on the right display, opening the spotlight (cmd + space) will open on the right display.